# Docker: Benefit of the "From"-Instructions?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, docker

i have a question about docker (http://docker.io).

In the tutorial part there is described, that every dockerfile should contain a "From" instruction.

My question is: What is the benefit for this instruction? Does this mean my local docker daemon can run basic images of cent os or debian when the host is ubuntu?

I believe to understand the basics and some details. Docker uses cgroups and aufs to split processes in different containers. cgroups are kernel features so it's expecting to run on a linux kernel os.

Usually i use docker through vagrant on windows 8 so it could be there are some mistakes in my thoughts^^ Excuse me for my bad english...

Thanks in regards,

Tenjio

Comment: Think "golden image".

Answer (score 1):

> What is the benefit for this instruction?

From the Docker documentation :

> The FROM instruction sets the Base Image for subsequent instructions.
>   As such, a valid Dockerfile must have FROM as its first instruction.
>   The image can be any valid image – it is especially easy to start by
>   pulling an image from the Public Repositories.

Basically, the benefit of the `FROM` instruction is to start from a base image with installed software. If you browse the [catalog](https://index.docker.io) of images you will see that there is a lot of existing configuration with their own software or stack installed. This allows a developer to write a Dockerfile beginning from an existing container configuration. So let's say you want to build a container but you want to benefit from existing expertise from a team that has already built a base image, you could benefit from it using the `FROM` instruction.

Note that in the future it might be allowed to chain `FROM` instructions so you could split Dockerfiles into smaller pieces. So instead of having a huge Dockerfile with many `RUN` instructions to install your stack, you will split it into smaller reusable pieces using the `FROM` instruction in a Dockerfile to reference another one.

> Does this mean my local docker daemon can run basic images of cent os
>   or debian when the host is ubuntu?

Simply, Yes.